# Wix Custom Action being skipped when it shouldn't

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, custom-action

I'm new to Wix, so I might be missing something basic, but I can't figure out why my custom action isn't being executed.

**My Setup**

I have an installer that does 3 things: 1) Installs the client app, 2) Updates the database to which the app is linked, and 3) Deploys reports to the report server. I have created a dialog with checkboxes that allows the user to choose what combination of these 3 things the installer should do.

[image: Screenshot of Config Options Dialog]

My features and custom actions are defined like this:

```
<Feature Id="MainProduct" Title="ARCtax" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="RegistryComponents" />

  <Condition Level="0">
    <![CDATA[(NOT INSTALL_OPTION_1) and (NOT REMOVE = "ALL")]]>
  </Condition>
    </Feature>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunSqlScripts" Sequence="6598">
    <![CDATA[ALLOW_DB_UPDATE = "yes" and INSTALL_OPTION_2 = "1"]]>
  </Custom>
  <Custom Action="RunRsSetup" Sequence="6599">
    <![CDATA[ALLOW_RS_DEPLOY = "yes" and ((ALLOW_DB_UPDATE = "yes" and INSTALL_OPTION_3 = "1") or (ALLOW_DB_UPDATE = "no" and INSTALL_OPTION_2 = "1"))]]>
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

- *INSTALL_OPTION_1* = The 1st checkbox on the configuration dialog. This controls whether or not the app is installed.
- *INSTALL_OPTION_2* = The 2nd checkbox on the configuration dialog. When ALLOW_DB_UPDATE = "yes", this controls whether the database is updated, otherwise it controls whether reports are deployed.
- *INSTALL_OPTION_3* = The 3rd checkbox on the configuration dialog. This controls whether reports are deployed when ALLOW_DB_UPDATE = "yes", otherwise it is hidden
- *ALLOW_DB_UPDATE* = Property set by another custom action. If the database connection fails, or the database is already up to date, this is "no" otherwise "yes".
- *ALLOW_RS_DEPLOY* = Property set by another custom action. If the connection to the report server is successfully established, this is set to "yes" otherwise "no".

**The Problem**

The problem I'm having is that when I uncheck the first checkbox, but leave the other 2 checked (Don't install the app, but update the database and deploy the reports). The custom actions don't execute. The reason I need this behavior to work is that there could be situations where the user would need to reinstall the reports, or update another database, but not need to reinstall the app.

My 2 custom actions that update the database and deploy the reports are the last 2 actions to occur in the InstallExecuteSequence before InstallFinalize

[image: Orca Screenshot of InstallExecuteSequence]

When I run the installer with verbose logging, it says that those 2 actions are skipped because the condition is false, but as far as I can see, it shouldn't be. Can anyone give me some pointers? Below is the log (as much as I thought relevant/stackoverflow would allow me to include)

***UI Log***

```
Action 11:55:15: WelcomeDlg. 
Action start 11:55:15: WelcomeDlg.
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:15:057]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:15:057]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For ARCtaxInstall_Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Verdana' font, in 1 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:15:066]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:15:066]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For ARCtaxInstall_Font_Header textstyle, the system created a 'Verdana' font, in 1 character set, of 23 pixels height.
Action 11:55:15: WelcomeDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:074]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CostingComplete property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: BindImage 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ProgId 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PublishComponent 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: SelfReg 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Font 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Shortcut 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Icon 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
MSI (c) (AC:C8) [11:55:15:075]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:16:910]: Doing action: FetchConnectionInfo
Action 11:55:16: FetchConnectionInfo. 
Action start 11:55:16: FetchConnectionInfo.
MSI (c) (AC:E8) [11:55:16:913]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\astarr\AppData\Local\Temp\MSID386.tmp, Entrypoint: FetchExistingConnection
MSI (c) (AC:DC) [11:55:16:915]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (AC:DC) [11:55:16:915]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (AC:DC) [11:55:16:916]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (AC!50) [11:55:17:249]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SERVER_NAME property. Its value is '**********'.
MSI (c) (AC!50) [11:55:17:250]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE_NAME property. Its value is '**********'.
Action ended 11:55:17: FetchConnectionInfo. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:17:282]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:17:282]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For ARCtaxInstall_Font_Normal__UL textstyle, the system created a 'Verdana' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Action 11:55:17: ConnectionSelectDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:17:782]: Doing action: AllowDbUpdateOption
Action 11:55:17: AllowDbUpdateOption. 
Action start 11:55:17: AllowDbUpdateOption.
MSI (c) (AC:80) [11:55:17:785]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\astarr\AppData\Local\Temp\MSID6F2.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckDbUpdate
MSI (c) (AC!C0) [11:55:18:252]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ALLOW_DB_UPDATE property. Its value is 'yes'.
Action ended 11:55:19: AllowDbUpdateOption. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:19:824]: Doing action: AllowRsDeployOption
Action 11:55:19: AllowRsDeployOption. 
Action start 11:55:19: AllowRsDeployOption.
MSI (c) (AC:3C) [11:55:19:827]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\astarr\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIDEE3.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckRsPermission
MSI (c) (AC!B0) [11:55:21:760]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ALLOW_RS_DEPLOY property. Its value is 'yes'.
Action ended 11:55:23: AllowRsDeployOption. Return value 1.
Action 11:55:23: InstallOptionsDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:25:030]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting INSTALL_OPTION_1 property. Its current value is '1'.
Action 11:55:26: DestinationSelectDlg. Dialog created
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:27:185]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (AC:20) [11:55:27:185]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898 
Info 2898.For ARCtaxInstall_Font_Bold textstyle, the system created a 'Verdana' font, in 1 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Action 11:55:27: ConfirmInstallDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 11:55:28: WelcomeDlg. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (AC:A4) [11:55:28:472]: Doing action: ProgressDlg
Action 11:55:28: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 11:55:28: ProgressDlg.
Action 11:55:28: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 11:55:28: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
```

***Execute Sequence Log***

```
Action start 11:55:28: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:575]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:575]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 11:55:28: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 11:55:28: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:576]: Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: already done on client side
Action ended 11:55:28: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:577]: Doing action: AppSearch
Action 11:55:28: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 11:55:28: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:577]: Skipping AppSearch action: already done on client side
Action ended 11:55:28: AppSearch. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:578]: Skipping action: SetINSTALLFOLDER (condition is false)
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:578]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
Action 11:55:28: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 11:55:28: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 11:55:28: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:578]: Doing action: ValidateProductID
Action 11:55:28: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 11:55:28: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 11:55:28: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:580]: Doing action: CostInitialize
Action 11:55:28: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:55:28: CostInitialize.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:580]: Machine policy value 'MaxPatchCacheSize' is 10
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:581]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ROOTDRIVE property. Its value is 'C:\'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:581]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CostingComplete property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:581]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:581]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:582]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:582]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: __MsiPatchFileList 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:582]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:582]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: PatchPackage 4: SELECT `DiskId`, `PatchId`, `LastSequence` FROM `Media`, `PatchPackage` WHERE `Media`.`DiskId`=`PatchPackage`.`Media_` ORDER BY `DiskId`  
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:582]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
Action ended 11:55:28: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:582]: Doing action: FileCost
Action 11:55:28: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:55:28: FileCost.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:583]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiAssembly 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:583]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:583]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:583]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
Action ended 11:55:28: FileCost. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:583]: Doing action: CostFinalize
Action 11:55:28: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 11:55:28: CostFinalize.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OutOfDiskSpace property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OutOfNoRbDiskSpace property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiAssembly 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiAssembly 4:  SELECT `MsiAssembly`.`Attributes`, `MsiAssembly`.`File_Application`, `MsiAssembly`.`File_Manifest`,  `Component`.`KeyPath` FROM `MsiAssembly`, `Component` WHERE  `MsiAssembly`.`Component_` = `Component`.`Component` AND `MsiAssembly`.`Component_` = ? 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLFOLDER property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Appraisal Research Corp\ARCtax_Test_Installer'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:584]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETDIR property. Its value is 'C:\'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ManufactureDir property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Appraisal Research Corp\'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLFOLDER property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\Appraisal Research Corp\ARCtax_Test_Installer'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files\Appraisal Research Corp\ARCtax_Test_Installer\'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Target path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Note: target paths subject to change (via custom actions or browsing)
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Dir (target): Key: TARGETDIR    , Object: C:\
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Dir (target): Key: WindowsFolder    , Object: C:\WINDOWS\
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Dir (target): Key: ProgramFiles64Folder , Object: C:\Program Files\
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Dir (target): Key: ManufactureDir   , Object: C:\Program Files\Appraisal Research Corp\
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Dir (target): Key: INSTALLFOLDER    , Object: C:\Program Files\Appraisal Research Corp\ARCtax_Test_Installer\
Action ended 11:55:28: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:585]: Doing action: MigrateFeatureStates
Action 11:55:28: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 11:55:28: MigrateFeatureStates.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:586]: Skipping MigrateFeatureStates action: already done on client side
Action ended 11:55:28: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:586]: Doing action: InstallValidate
Action 11:55:28: InstallValidate. Validating install
Action start 11:55:28: InstallValidate.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its current value is '1102d8f96701ca4ea7c1ec85069c9dad'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Feature: MainProduct; Installed: Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Component: TestApp; Installed: Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Component: ProductRegistryKey; Installed: Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Component: __ProductRegistryKey65; Installed: Null;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: BindImage 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ProgId 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PublishComponent 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: SelfReg 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Font 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Shortcut 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Icon 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:587]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:589]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CostingComplete property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:589]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: BindImage 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:589]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ProgId 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:589]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PublishComponent 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:589]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: SelfReg 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Font 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Shortcut 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Icon 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:590]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: FilesInUse 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:609]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
Action ended 11:55:28: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:611]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
Action 11:55:28: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
Action start 11:55:28: RemoveExistingProducts.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:612]: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall
Action ended 11:55:28: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:612]: Doing action: InstallInitialize
Action 11:55:28: InstallInitialize. 
Action start 11:55:28: InstallInitialize.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:613]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:613]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:613]: BeginTransaction: Locking Server
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:614]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:614]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:614]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:614]: Server not locked: locking for product {E0A31102-EAA7-4C51-8BFF-AA83722FA29A}
Action ended 11:55:28: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:623]: Doing action: ProcessComponents
Action 11:55:28: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
Action start 11:55:28: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 11:55:28: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:625]: Doing action: UnpublishFeatures
Action 11:55:28: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
Action start 11:55:28: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 11:55:28: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:626]: Doing action: RemoveRegistryValues
Action 11:55:28: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
Action start 11:55:28: RemoveRegistryValues.
Action ended 11:55:28: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:628]: Doing action: RemoveFiles
Action 11:55:28: RemoveFiles. Removing files
Action start 11:55:28: RemoveFiles.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:629]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: RemoveFile 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:629]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: RemoveFile 
Action ended 11:55:28: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:629]: Doing action: InstallFiles
Action 11:55:28: InstallFiles. Copying new files
Action start 11:55:28: InstallFiles.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Patch 4: SELECT `Patch`.`File_`, `Patch`.`Header`, `Patch`.`Attributes`, `Patch`.`Sequence`, `Patch`.`StreamRef_` FROM `Patch` WHERE `Patch`.`File_` = ? AND `Patch`.`#_MsiActive`=? ORDER BY `Patch`.`Sequence` 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1302 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiSFCBypass 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiSFCBypass 4: SELECT `File_` FROM `MsiSFCBypass` WHERE `File_` = ? 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:630]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 4: SELECT `Header` FROM `MsiPatchHeaders` WHERE `StreamRef` = ? 
Action ended 11:55:28: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:631]: Doing action: WriteRegistryValues
Action 11:55:28: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
Action start 11:55:28: WriteRegistryValues.
Action ended 11:55:28: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:632]: Doing action: RegisterUser
Action 11:55:28: RegisterUser. Registering user
Action start 11:55:28: RegisterUser.
Action ended 11:55:28: RegisterUser. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:633]: Doing action: RegisterProduct
Action 11:55:28: RegisterProduct. Registering product
Action start 11:55:28: RegisterProduct.
Action 11:55:28: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
GenerateScript: Registering product
Action ended 11:55:28: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:644]: Doing action: PublishFeatures
Action 11:55:28: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
Action start 11:55:28: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 11:55:28: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:649]: Doing action: PublishProduct
Action 11:55:28: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
Action start 11:55:28: PublishProduct.
PublishProduct: 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: Resolving source to launched-from source.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: Setting launched-from source as last-used.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourcedirProduct property. Its value is '{E0A31102-EAA7-4C51-8BFF-AA83722FA29A}'.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: SOURCEDIR ==> C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:656]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {E0A31102-EAA7-4C51-8BFF-AA83722FA29A}
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:657]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:657]: Source type from package 'Installer_ARCtax.msi': 2
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:657]: SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\SourceHash{E0A31102-EAA7-4C51-8BFF-AA83722FA29A}
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:683]: Source path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:683]: Dir (source): Key: TARGETDIR    , Object: C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\ , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:683]: Dir (source): Key: WindowsFolder    , Object: C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\ , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:683]: Dir (source): Key: ProgramFiles64Folder , Object: C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\ , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:683]: Dir (source): Key: ManufactureDir   , Object: C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\ , LongSubPath: Appraisal Research Corp\ , ShortSubPath: 8ii-ewho\
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:683]: Dir (source): Key: INSTALLFOLDER    , Object: C:\Users\astarr\Source\Repos\ARCtax\ARCtax\ARC2010NewMenu\ARCMenu\ARCMenu\Installer_ARCtax\bin\x64\Debug\ , LongSubPath: Appraisal Research Corp\ARCtax_Test_Installer\   , ShortSubPath: 8ii-ewho\v7651isb\
Action ended 11:55:28: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:684]: Skipping action: RunSqlScripts (condition is false)
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:684]: Skipping action: RunRsSetup (condition is false)
MSI (s) (6C:C0) [11:55:28:684]: Doing action: InstallFinalize
Action 11:55:28: InstallFinalize.
```

I suppose I should also note that when I leave the 1st checkbox checked, the other options work as they should.

**Edit**

I almost forgot, this issue only happens when the application is already installed. If it's not and I deselect the 1st checkbox, the database will still be updated and reports will still be deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the scenario is that you run the MSI again and it goes into maintenance mode and shows the Welcome dialog again, and then you choose the checkboxes again...

Make sure that you declare the properties as secure. That tends to be the main reason that property values don't migrate from the UI to the installer service.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thanks.